# Как в assembler записать вторую букву

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Есть такой простейший код в emu8086:

```
ORG 100h

MOV AH, 02h
MOV DL, 41h
INT 21h
INT 20h

RET
```

Выводит букву `A`.

А как написать набор букв, пример: `ABCD` так, чтобы не наложились друг другу?

Comment: Скопируйте код `MOV AH, 02h
MOV DL, 41h
INT 21h`
нужное количество раз, вместо 41h подставьте код необходимых символов

Answer (score 3):

Например, [int 21h / функция 9](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0017.php), если нужно именно через DOS. Если через BIOS - [int 10h, функции 9 и 0Ah](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0009.php).

P.S. ОМГ, сколько мамонтова д...ма в голове сохранилось! Б-р-р-р...